# Somar valores da coluna do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, data

Estou fazendo um sistema de relatórios e no banco irá ter, por exemplo:

```
> - visualizacoes | 300
> - clicks | 20
> - data | 2015-06-03

> - visualizacoes | 230
> - clicks | 3
> - data | 2015-06-03

> - visualizacoes | 340
> - clicks | 10
> - data | 2015-07-01
```

Então meu problema é, que vai ter 2 registros ou mais a data (Mẽs) igual, como no exemplo acima que tem dois com o mês **06**. Preciso somar os clicks e visualizacoes do mesmo mês e exibir 1 resultado só (já somado) na `query`.

Tenho o código

```
$relatorios = $this->db->query("SELECT visualizacoes, clicks, MONTH(data) AS mes FROM relatorio WHERE YEAR(data) = '".date('Y')."' ORDER BY data ASC");
```

Mas esse só está organizando para fazer o relatório do ano atual, mas não tenho noção como colocar algo pra somar o mesmo mês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(visualizacoes),
  SUM(clicks),
  MONTH(data) AS mes
FROM relatorio
WHERE YEAR(data) = '2015'
GROUP BY mes
ORDER BY mes ASC
```

SQL Fiddle [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98ab7/1).

A mágica acontece no `GROUP BY`. O que ele faz, grosso modo, é que ele pega o resultado da sua consulta, separa as linhas em grupinhos com base nas colunas que você especificou, e executa “aggregate functions” (imagino que seja “funções agregadas” em português, mas não tenho certeza) pra juntar as linhas de cada grupinho de volta em uma linha só. No caso, como você quer somar, você usa a `SUM` (tem outras funções para achar máximos, mínimos, médias, … a lista completa está disponível na [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)).

Comment: Foi isso mesmo que fiz. Postei a dúvida e depois tentei e meu código ficou quase igual ao seu, o meu `SELECT SUM(visualizacoes) as visualizacao, SUM(clicks) as click, MONTH(data) AS mes FROM relatorio WHERE YEAR(data) = '".date('Y')."' GROUP BY MONTH(data) ORDER BY data ASC`... Muito obrigado!