# Somar valores retornados de while

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabla que tem a coluna valor, eu faço a consulta desses valores da seguinte forma

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM comisao_trabalho WHERE idJob="10" && pagoA="Dalton" ORDER BY id ASC';
$buscar = $conexao->prepare($sql2); 
$buscar->execute();

$retorno = array();
$retorno['dados'] = '';
$retorno['qtd'] = $buscar->rowCount();

if($retorno['qtd'] > 0):

    while($conteudo = $buscar->fetchObject()){
        $retorno['dados'] = $conteudo->valor;
    }                                            

    echo json_encode($retorno);
endif;
```

Os valores estão nesse formato: U$ 2.500,00

Comment: Você quer o valor total?

Comment: Sim, a consulta me retorna por exemplo: 'U$ 2.500,00', 'U$ 750,00', U$ 1.000,00' . Preciso somar todos os valores que meu while me trouxer

Comment: Fiz uma resposta, caso você tenha restrições quanto a consulta SQL peço que informe, assim editarei a mesma. Se isto acontecer você vai precisar utilizar de uma variável "contador" que recebe ela mesma e o valor da linha atual, dentro do WHILE.

Comment: Reparei outro detalhe, que sua coluna `valor`tem os valores salvos no formato String, não é interessante que você salve os mesmos desta forma, normalmente o símbolo de moeda (no seu caso dólar, U$) é adicionado via HTML ou PHP quando serão mostrados os dados ao usuário. Utilize formato Double (Float) para salvar valores.

Comment: A resposta do nosso amigo Leandro Silva dá uma visão de como seria a variável auxiliar (cont) que falei.

Comment: Intendi, mas da mesma forma eu precisaria salvar o valor sem cifão ou eu poderia usar preg_replace no $conteudo->valor para deixar apenas os números?

Comment: Se você utilizar a forma que nosso amigo Leandro sugeriu, pode utilizar o preg_replace() para deixar apenas o valor e já será possível realizar a soma. Via comando SQL a soma só será retornada se você guardar os valores sem cifrão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer o VALOR_TOTAL diretamente via SQL e apelidando um campo, neste caso sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT id, idJob, pagoA, SUM(valor) AS valorTotal 
FROM comisao_trabalho 
WHERE idJob="10" && pagoA="Dalton" 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Não é aconselhável que você utilize SELECT * FROM, apenas para testes.
O campo `AS` atribui um apelido a tabela, você pode colocar qualquer nome, quer dizer que a soma dos valores da coluna `valor`serão colocados em uma coluna imaginária chamada `valorTotal`.

No PHP você teria ao dispor uma coluna chamada valorTotal que retorna a soma dos valores.

Ex.: `$retorno['dados'] = $conteudo->valorTotal;`

> É importante lembrar que neste exemplo você terá o retorno de uma linha, ou seja, um registro com o valorTotal dos demais que caíram na cláusula **WHERE.**

#### Saiba mais

- **SUM()**: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp
- [Somar valores da coluna do banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67504/somar-valores-da-coluna-do-banco-de-dados?rq=1)

Comment: Intendi Tiago, realmente essa seria a melhor solução. Mas para não mexer em tudo que já esta pronto, eu poderia adicionar uma coluna "copia", no qual eu coloco os mesmos valores que estão na "original" mas sem cifrão nem pontos correto?

Comment: Claro que depois desse alerta, é bom eu me acostumar a salvar valores sem cifrão e adicioná-los posteriormente. Obrigado

Comment: @daltongonzaloFuentes você pode criar uma outra coluna que armazenará o tipo de moeda. Ex.: moeda, cifrao, etc. Que terá valores como “R$, U$”. Neste caso na exibição você concatenaria os dois campos (no PHP se bem lembro é utilizado . [ponto final] para isso. Ao salvar apenas os valores na respectiva coluna é possível garantir que poderemos manipular os mesmos efetuando operações aritméticas dentro do próprio banco de dados, sem depender de funções ou arrays da linguagem de programação, como str_replace(), split() [em java], implode() e explode(), etc

Comment: @daltongonzaloFuentes você pode sim fazer uma coluna "cópia" sem nenhum problema. Inclusive dá pra fazer uma query que irá extrair os dados, separar o cifrão e jogar cada um para sua coluna no banco de dados, assim ela automatizaria e organizaria seus registros, depois você poderia remover a coluna valor. Há várias formas, inclusive via SQL você consegue remover o cifrão de todos os registros com um só comando.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode somar com uma variável auxiliar dentro do while:

```
$aux = 0;
while($conteudo = $buscar->fetchObject()){
    $aux += $conteudo->valor;
}
$retorno['dados'] = $aux;
```

E no final da iteração do while, você teria o valor total guardado na $aux

Comment: Mas ai eu teria o problema do cifão não é?

Comment: Sim, neste caso não é possível somar Strings, Leandro tente dar uma editada na sua resposta com um implode() separando o cifrão e somando os valores, acredito que pode ajudar nosso amigo.

Comment: Obrigado @TiagoBoeing e Leandro, utilizei a sua mesmo Leandro, mais por facilidade pois já tinha muita coisa pronta. Mas ambas deram certo!